# Return result from a property on specific condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datetime property and want to get result on specific condition.

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

if Date = DateTime.Min then it should return blank otherwise actual result. so how to get it from this property by writing code in get here.
please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by `return blank`? DateTime is a non-nullable value type.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement a backing field, in order to be able to compare with `DateTime.MinValue`.

Also, since you wish to return "nothing", you can change the type of property to nullable DateTime (`DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`).

Here's what your target implementation might look like:

```
private DateTime? dt;
public DateTime? Date 
{ 
  get => dt == DateTime.MinValue ? null : dt;
  set => dt = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` in C# can not be blank. You may use below syntax to return `null`.

```
private DateTime? date 
public DateTime? Date 
{ 

  get
     {
       if(date == DateTime.Min)
     {
         return null;
     }
         return date;
     }

   set
     {
         date = value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define DateTime as Nullable. Saying blank is a bit ambiguous. You can return null and also define additional property in order to support returning empty string such as ;

```
private DateTime? _dt;
public DateTime? Date
{
    get
    {
        if (!this._dt.HasValue)
            return null;

        return this._dt.Value == DateTime.MinValue ? null : this._dt;
    }
    set
    {
        this._dt = value;
    }
}

public string DateAsString
{
    get
    {
        if (!this._dt.HasValue)
            return string.Empty;

        return this._dt.Value == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : this._dt.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```